# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ecommerce'

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to python and I cannot get my head around why I am facing with the error in title.

This is my project structure:

[image]

and this is what I have inside shipping.py module:

```
def calc_shipping():
    print('Calculating shipping...')
```

so when I do -> from ecommerce.shipping import calc_shipping

and want to use calc_shipping()

I get error ->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/burakhanaksoy/gitHub/Python/PythonStudy/bman/basics/modules/app.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ecommerce.shipping import calc_shipping
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ecommerce'
```

any help is appreciated.

best,

PS: I get the same error in PyCharm as well, in fact in PyCharm, it doesn't even auto-fill 'ecommerce' or 'ecommerce.shipping' as I type
`from ecommerce.shipping import calc_shipping`

[image]

Comment: try basics.ecommerce.shipping or change "modules" to python module?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Neeraj, it worked now. I can upvote if you answer the question.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On such scenarios always check following things:

1. if the module has init, in other words if its a python module
2. check if its accessible from parent dir, in this example basics.